# How to properly configure my backend in order to receive data from my form? I'm using Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

My goal is to send emails with nodemailer, so I need to do that from my backend. I have a form in my vue component and I'm trying to send the data to http://localhost:3000/ but I get an error : POST http://localhost:3000/ 404 (Not Found). I'm using Axios to do that.
When I make a get request I get a response without any errors, but I cannot make a post request.
First, I created a server just to deploy my site on heroku (responsive proposes), but now I'm not sure if my backend configuration is ok to receive data from my client side. I looked around but I didn't find a specific answer to my problem.

Contact.vue:

```
<form class="form" @submit.prevent="sendData">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <label for="name">Name</label>
                        <input type="text" id="name" name="user_name" v-model="name">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label for="mail">E-mail</label>
                        <input type="email" id="mail" name="user_email" v-model="email">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label for="msg">Message:</label>
                        <textarea id="msg" name="user_message" v-model="message"></textarea>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <button type="submit" class="btn">Send</button>
            </form>




    <script>
import * as axios from 'axios';
export default {
    data(){
        return{
            name: "", 
            email: "", 
            message: ""
        }
    },
    methods: {
       sendData(){
           console.log(this.name, this.email,this.message);
           axios.post("http://localhost:3000/",{
               name: this.name,
               email: this.email,
               message: this.message
           })
         .then(response => {
            console.log(response)
         })
         .catch(error =>{
            this.error = error;
         }) 
       }
    }
}
</script>
```

My server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var cors = require('cors')
const app = express();
app.use(cors())

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/dist/"));

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/dist/index.html'); 
})


app.listen(port);

console.log('Server started...');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending a `POST` request to `http://localhost:3000/`, but this is set as a `GET` in your server. So try:

```
app.post("/", function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/dist/index.html'); 
})
```